# How to query using join in Supabase?

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

In Supabase documentation, it explains this as how you would "join" tables to get data

```
const { data, error } = await Supabase
  .from('countries')
  .select(`
    name,
    cities (
      name
    )
  `)
```

But how do I know this works every time when I have not specified which columns would be joined? Is there a way to specify which column to perform join on?

Comment: I have a same problem for pulling data from supabase database.
I like to join tables and select values from multiple tables at once. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

So this code works when there is only one relation(foreign key) between the two table countries and cities

```
const { data, error } = await Supabase
  .from('countries')
  .select(`
    name,
    cities (
      name
    )
  `)
```

Or when you want to join multiple tables, you can do this:

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('products')
  .select(`
    id,
    supplier:supplier_id ( name ),
    purchaser:purchaser_id ( name )
  `)
```

Comment: I am facing a similar issue but for a join one more level deep. e.g. here we are selecting countries, and then joining to get the cities. Say after this, I wanted to get the cafes in the cities, and assuming the FK are all configured.

`.select(\`name, cities (name, restaurants (name))\`)`

does this work? In my case it just shows up as null

Comment: @KennyJohnJacob I have never seen a Supabase query like that, so I'm not sure, but it might be worth posting to Supabase discussion page https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions

Comment: @KennyJohnJacob That should work as well, it's documented on https://postgrest.org/en/v9.0/api.html#nested-embedding

Comment: Can someone please point to necessary documentation where how there queries are structured and work are detailed? I only see example queries everywhere. Please point to some nice resources.

Comment: @AkashGorai Would the official Supabase documentation be what you were looking for? https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select

Comment: @dshukertjr! what kinds of value will be replaced with supplier and supplier_id?

Comment: @Cardoso `supplier` can be anything you would like. `supplier_id` is the column within the table that you passed to the `from` clause.

Comment: The join field comes out as an object. Anyway for it to be just one value?

Comment: @AmarjeetSinghRai You cannot do it yet, but a feature to spread the nested object in the parent object is coming to Supabase soon. https://supabase.com/blog/postgrest-11-prerelease#spreading-related-tables Until this feature lands, you would have to use Database Functions https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/functions

Comment: This solution is working for me as well. Thank you so much amigo.