# How to pull data from multi tables at once from supabase tables?

Tags: javascript, supabase

I have some tables on supabase db. 
There is a post table and it contains user_id from profiles table. 
 `user_id` field related with the id of profiles table. 
I am using `@supabase` node module for pulling data from supabase. 
 I can pull data with single query, but I don't know the way of pulling data from multiple tables with a query.
I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64996432/how-to-query-using-join-in-supabase), but it doesn't help me. The response's result doesn't contain the profile information.

Here is the code I tried to use.

```
await supabase
  .from('posts')
  .select(`user_id,
    profiles(
      first_name
    )
  `);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query using join in Supabase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64996432/how-to-query-using-join-in-supabase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a foreign key relationship between your `user_id` column and the `profiles` table, the following will return you the posts data as well as the profiles data of user_id on each posts row.

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('posts')
  .select(`*,
    profiles(
      first_name
    )
  `);
```

If this does not work, you probably do not have a foreign key relationship between the `user_id` column and `profiles` table. You can read the official guide on how to add foreign key relationship.
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/tables#joining-tables-with-foreign-keys